# SSL and https issues for webapp

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

i am trying to set up https for  webapp. I set up an ssl cert from letsencrypt. My domain name is now routing to https but it is going straight to apache2 homepage. My sites-available default-ssl.conf file looks as follows

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ServerName domain-names.com
            ServerAlias www.domain-name.com
            #ProxyPass / http://domain-name.com:8080/
            #ProxyPassReverse / https://domain-name.com:443/
```

Unfortunately, before i attempted this i could access my webapp via ip_address:80/myapp.. Now i am getting a 502 proxy error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Is the webapp still running ?

Comment: Hi, The webapp is running on Tomcat,  and Tomcat is running and listening on port 8080. Even if i could get the domain name to open the tomcat page it would be a help.